# redirecting to a link after clicking on a mysql ajax dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i'm working on a search menu with suggestion dropdown menu underneath it. Where if you click on the suggestion, you should redirect to the product.

Im currently using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("./includes/backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
                var link = data;
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
        window.location = link;
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is my searchbox in html

```
<div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search product..." />
            <div class="result"></div>
        </div>
```

I'm currently trying to open a link by using the window.location function in the onclick function. Where the link is set as a var from the data that's been suggested.

For so far it's not working, its not opening any links or so.
Has anyone a idea how to fix this?
Thanks, - Julian.

Comment: First thing check on click is it feeling the value in "$(this).text()"

Comment: You are setting var link = data; ... So you think its proper link ?? console.log(link)

Comment: Your 'link' variable is a local variable within the callback function. Define the variable at the beginning of the script and assign value 'data' in the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to achieve something like this. You have mistaken declaration for link. you should make it global declared. Hope it work for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var link;
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
           for(var i = 0; i<= 20; i++){
                var suggessions = "<p>" + i + "</p>";
                resultDropdown.html(suggessions);
                link = i;
            }
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
        console.log(link);
        window.location = link;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search product..." />
            <div class="result"></div>
        </div>
```

The Actual Js Code you gone write is like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var link;
        $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
            /* Get input value on change */
            var inputVal = $(this).val();
            var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
            if(inputVal.length){
               $.get("./includes/backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
            // Display the returned data in browser
            resultDropdown.html(data);
            link = data;
        });
            } else{
                resultDropdown.empty();
            }
        });

        // Set search input value on click of result item
        $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
            $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
            $(this).parent(".result").empty();
            console.log(link);
            window.location = link;
        });
    });
```

This will work for you.

Comment: It's not working for me because now im missing this part of the code that actually returns the suggestion out of the database where it searches for the product if its available 

 $.get("./includes/backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
                var link = data;
            });

Comment: Yes... obviously ... you need to replace that thing.

Comment: Replace my code in if(inputVal.length) with yours. Take care of brackets.

Comment: check answer again ... I have wrote new code at last in which you have to do nothing ... just copy paste it